# How can I get Ctrl+Alt+F* working?| Why runlevel doesn't starts automatically?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, tty

I googled many threads on my problem, but most of them are about proprietary drivers and black screen (although user can login blindly into tty*). My question isn't about that type of problem but the following:

I have Ubuntu 11.04, Ati Radeon HD2400 mobility video card with installed up-to-date proprietary drivers (fglrx) which works normal with Compiz.

`ps aux|grep tty` returns only one with X:

```
root      1083  5.1  7.1 296396 148148 tty7    Ss+  Oct18  54:08 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-vTLeqW/database -nolisten tcp vt7
```

cat /etc/default/console-setup |egrep -v "^#"

```
VERBOSE_OUTPUT="no"  
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-4]"  
CHARMAP="UTF-8"  
CODESET="Uni2"  
FONTFACE="Fixed"  
FONTSIZE="16"  
if [ -f /etc/default/keyboard ]; then  
    . /etc/default/keyboard  
fi
```

And when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> am getting a blinking underscore cursor and nothing else.

I have no directory `/etc/event.d/` to search ttys in it.

Okay after a hint (to check /etc/init/tty*.conf) I realized that runlevel 3/5 didn't ran automatically:
`runlevel` returns: `runlevel unknown`
`echo $RUNLEVEL` returns "" (nothing)

and `sudo init 5` bringed to me ctrl+alt+F* console login prompts.
But keybord works only on tty1.
`ps aux|grep tty` now returns one with X, and tty1:

```
root      1083  3.4  6.2 267172 128944 tty7    Ss+  Oct18  66:37 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-vTLeqW/database -nolisten tcp vt7  
root      2722  0.0  0.0   1872   580 tty1     Ss+  16:40   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

why?

Second question is: **Why runlevel 3/5 doesn't start automatically?**

Comment: Do you have the files `/etc/init/tty[1.4].conf' ? If they got lost somehow, recreate them.

Comment: They are okay. But now I can't determine current runlevel/ tried: runlevel, it returned "unknown", echo $RUNLEVEL returned ""